# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync failing in staging server

Tags: c#, api, web-applications, calendar

`GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()` fails on (farmed, 4.5 NET) staging server, but works great in local server. I have followed every code on the help line still no avail.

Here is my code:

```
String gpath = Server.MapPath("credentials/siteAPI.json");
UserCredential credential;

string credPath = Server.MapPath("credentials");

using (var stream = new FileStream(gpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
      credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },//
                    "xx@ccc.com",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                     new AppDataFileStore(credPath)
                    ).Result;
}
```

And I get this error:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
    at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
    at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line 59
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
    at z2.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\hostingspaces\cal1234\mysitecalendar.com\wwwroot\z2.aspx.cs:line 169
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
    at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
    at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line 59<---
```

According to other notes I read, this is due to permission issues on the server side, but with a farmed site, I have no more control on any permissions.

Interestingly enough, when I copy one of the approved credentials from my local server to the staging server then everything works! It seems that the staging server is not capable (or does not have the permission) to launch the screen to ask the user for token approval!

How do I solve this?

Comment: is gpath the file that you downloaded from google developer ? If so, did you copy the file to your project directly ?

Comment: If you have, make sure you will change Build Action to "Content" and Copy to output directory to "Copy always"

Comment: yes gpath is the credentials I downloaded from google developer console and yes I copied into my project locally and uploaded to my staging server as well.

Comment: the build action that I always use is the normal build website, should I use something else?

Comment: You need to use the Build Action to Content and Copy to output directory to "Copy always"

Comment: I have done this also still no luck

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours on the same problem and finally found a post which helped me resolve the issue for me.
The post is here http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/7819b19d-07d0-4584-a061-cace0688bfb2?category=sharepointdevelopment

On the dev server where this code worked for me, a token response file was created in the credPath (see this variable in the code above) folder.

I just copied this file over to the staging server where it didn't work for me.
That resolved the issue for me..

This is probably because the page a consent web page is shown (worked in the dev server) to the user and  under the circumstances the page could not be shown which causes this error.
Again this is all theory, but the above solution has worked for me.

Comment: I have done what you suggested before and all works well, but this is not the proper way to do it. the consent page MUST be shown to any user from teh staging server otherwise this method is useless. I have tried every blog and trick mnetioned but none worked for me, still get the same error... Any other ideas?